# Wordpress: Hiding empty Facets (divs) if they contain no value

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, facetwp

I am using the FacetWP plugin, which allows users to filter posts depending on certain parameters drawing from custom fields.

On their site, the plugin says you can hide empty facets using this code:

```
(function($) {
$(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
    $.each(FWP.settings.num_choices, function(key, val) {
        var $parent = $('.facetwp-facet-' + key).closest('.facetwp-facet');
        (0 === val) ? $parent.hide() : $parent.show();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Facets on my site are wrapped in a div with the class "facetwp-facet" (see www.wgeil.de/listings/ for an example), so this should be targeting that div, in theory.

Could someone explain why this is not working? I have tried recreating the issue in JSFiddle but it worked there, so I am not sure what the problem is. To clarify, I am loading the above code into my theme header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.closest('.facetwp-facet')` cause the div you want to hide itself has `.facetwp-facet and .facetwp-facet-' + key class`, so just remove `.closest('facetwp-facet')` and it will work.

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Add to the end

```js
(function($) {
    console.log('this page is runned function!!')
    $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        $.each(FWP.settings.num_choices, function(key, val) {

                        var $parent = $('.facetwp-facet-' + key)
                        console.log(val)
                        val == 0 ? $parent.hide() : $parent.show()
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```